# Why solving #2SAT in polynomial time implies P = NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, satisfiability, p-vs-np, counting

The wikipedia article for [#P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%99%AFP-complete) states that if we have a polynomial-time algorithm for a #P-complete problem, P = NP is true.

As #2SAT is #P-complete, this would mean that providing a polynomial-time algorithm for #2SAT implies P = NP.

But why exactly is that? It means that there is at least one NP-complete problem that can be reduced to #2SAT right?

Comment: Wikipedia defines "#P" as `the class of function problems of the form "compute f(x)", where f is the number of accepting paths of a nondeterministic Turing machine running in polynomial time`. 1) Since for any 3-SAT instance you can write a non-deterministic TM that solves this instance, by counting the number of its accepting parts (and comparing it with 0), you can solve 3-SAT. 2) This counting problem is in #P, and hence it has a reduction to #2-SAT (by #P-completeness). 3) Combining 1) and 2), you get a poly-time reduction from 3-SAT to #2-SAT.

Comment: @Dmitry thank you! it would be interesting to know how this reduction from 3SAT to #2SAT looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*The Complexity of Enumeration and Reliability Problems*](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/epdf/10.1137/0208032) by Leslie G. Valiant gives a series of reductions to prove that $\sharp\texttt{3SAT}\leqslant \sharp\texttt{2SAT}$. Since there is a trivial reduction from $\texttt{3SAT}$ to $\sharp\texttt{3SAT}$, you have the wanted reduction.

Comment: Alright, thank you! I will have a look into it, so reducing 3SAT to #2SAT definetely not seems trivial